# Converting velocity template in api gateway to be passed in typescript with AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, velocity-template-language

I'm using typescript with AWS CDK to generate a cloudFormation template for api gateway. I've a  Apache Velocity template that helps me convert my response. While I'm creating the API gateway using typescript. How can I pass the template from code itself. I need to pass my template in [responseTemplates in IntegrationOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.IntegrationResponse.html) interface which expects a string. I've not been able to find any reasonable way to convert it to string.

```
{
    "sellableQuantity": $inputRoot.quantity),
    "reservedQuantity": $inputRoot.reservedQuantity)
    "marketplaceInventories": [
        #foreach( $marketplaceInventory in $inputRoot.marketplaceInventories) )
            {
                "sellableQuantity": $marketplaceInventory.sellableQuantity,
                "marketplaceAttributes": {
                    #set( $marketplaceAttributes = $marketplaceInventory.marketplaceAttributes )
                    "marketplaceName": "$marketplaceAttributes.marketplaceName",
                    "channelName": "$marketplaceAttributes.channelName"
                }
            }
            #if( $foreach.hasNext ) , #end
        #end
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question really is "How do I define a long string without worrying about escaping special characters in javascript?"

I think a [javascript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is the best choice as it allows you to not worry about escaping or line continuation. Using backticks around your string and `String.raw` you can ensure that what you define will be passed verbatim:

```
let myVelocityTemplate = String.raw`{
    "sellableQuantity": $inputRoot.quantity),
    "reservedQuantity": $inputRoot.reservedQuantity)
    "marketplaceInventories": [
        #foreach( $marketplaceInventory in $inputRoot.marketplaceInventories) )
            {
                "sellableQuantity": $marketplaceInventory.sellableQuantity,
                "marketplaceAttributes": {
                    #set( $marketplaceAttributes = $marketplaceInventory.marketplaceAttributes )
                    "marketplaceName": "$marketplaceAttributes.marketplaceName",
                    "channelName": "$marketplaceAttributes.channelName"
                }
            }
            #if( $foreach.hasNext ) , #end
        #end
    ] 
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In `java`, is very simple:

```java
private GraphQLApi CreateGraphQLApi(String API_NAME) {
    return GraphQLApi.Builder.create(this, API_NAME + "_AppSyncApi")
            .name(API_NAME.concat("_AppSyncApi"))
            .schemaDefinitionFile(Constants.SCHEMA_PATH)
            .build();
}
```

You can pass the schema path and let the `cdk` load and deploy the resource.

I think that the `typescript` API have a 1 to 1 match with other languages